# Makefile 'ifneq' syntax error, Broadcom BCM43142

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, driver, broadcom

I am trying to install the driver for the Broadcom BCM43142 on Tails 1.1. I am trying to follow the guide at [Linux World](http://tuxthink.blogspot.nl/2013/11/installing-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless.html). My laptop (Sony Vaio Flip **SVF14N13CXB**) has an Intel i5, 64-bit processer, so I downloaded the files from the Broadcom website for linux. I `gunzip`'d and un`tar`'d the files. I got a **Makefile** and the **lib** and **src** folders. I ran `chmod +x ./Makefile` then `./Makefile`. Here is what I got back.

```
./Makefile: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `$()KERNELRELEASE'
./Makefile: line 21: `ifneq ($()KERNELRELEASE)'
```

Here is some conext from the Makefile.

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

  LINUXVER_GOODFOR_CFG80211:=$(strip $(shell \
    if [ "$(VERSION)" -ge "2" -a "$(PATCHLEVEL)" -ge "6" -a "$(SUBLEVEL)" -ge "32" -o     "$(VERSION)" -ge "3" ]; then \
      echo TRUE; \
    else \
      echo FALSE; \
    fi \
  ))
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Outch!*

`Makefile` are description file that gave rules to a program called `make` in order to build a software. Usually, `Makefile` are *not* executable -- even if that could be made by providing a proper *chebang* on the first line.

The proper usage of `Makefile` is to call the program `make` from *inside* the folder containing that makefile.

```
cd /path/to/my/driver/sources
make         # build the software
make install # install the newly build software on your system
```

A few things thought:

- You probably have a README or INSTALL file that explain you that
  already in the same folder.
- See `man make` for more datails about
  *make* itself.
- You should probably have asked that on http://superuser.com

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wasn't even thinking. I don't have `make` on Tails. Need to get it. >_< Sorry for posting in the wrong site.